# How can I ensure a value is only incremented once in Firestore?

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-firestore

Consider the following minimal example:

```js
const admin = require("firebase-admin")
admin.initializeApp({credential: "your creds here"})

const db = admin.firestore()

const fooRef: firebase.firestore.CollectionReference<firebase.firestore.DocumentData> =
  db.collection("foo")

setInterval(() => {
  fooRef
    .doc("bar")
    .update({
      anImportantCounter: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1),
    })
}, 5000)
```

If I had 2 instances of this code running (like during a rolling update), would it be possible to ensure that the value in the field `anImportantConuter`, doesn't get incremented twice every 5 seconds? For the sake of example, assume the timing intervals just happen to be in sync.

Near the top of this [firebase documentation page on distributed counters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/counters), it says

> In Cloud Firestore, you can only update a single document about once per second...

But I'm unsure if that means that the duplicate writes are put in a queue to be updated, or that they simply don't happen. If there is a pattern to solve this sort of thing, that would be ideal.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limitation that Firestore allows only one update per second of a single document is a soft limit as documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#soft_limits). The document points out that Cloud Firestore does not stop you from exceeding the thresholds of soft limit but doing so affects the performance. So this limit is not a hard limit and you can surpass the limit in short bursts. In your case the two instances of the same code can both get executed (say, during a rolling update) as the limit is a soft limit. But sustaining a write rate above once per second increases latency and causes contention errors.

Now if you want the document to be updated once within the 5 seconds no matter how many requests were created, you need to set some sort of conditions inside the code so that only one request is processed. You should also look into the distributed counter solution mentioned [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/counters#solution_distributed_counters) that works around the per-document write limit by sharding data across multiple documents.

Now to avoid any conflicts you should consider using [transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transactions). In case of concurrent edit, Firestore runs the entire transaction again. To avoid duplicate updates you can store the last update or request commit timestamp in Firestore as mentioned in [this example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#data_validation_for_atomic_operations) so that new requests can compare or reference to make sure that a duplicate update is not performed.